# Rank of orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-transformations

I was thinking about a thing while working with orthogonal projections. Namely, is it always the case that when we linearly transform a vector u in R^3 with a matrix A where A orthogonally projects our vector u onto a plane in R^3, that the rank of A becomes one less in dimension, in this case 2?

If yes, why is that the case and is there some general intution about it that can be applied to spaces with higher dimensions? If no, what different scenarios are possible regarding the rank when we orthogonally project a vector in R^3 onto a plane. Is

I hope I was clear!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rank of a matrix $A$ is, by definition, the dimension of its column space, that is, the dimension of the *range* of the associated linear map $\varphi_A:=x\mapsto Ax$.

If $A$ (or rather, $\varphi_A$) is a (not necessarily orthogonal) projection to a subspace $W$, then its range is simply $W$ and thus, its rank is indeed the same as $\dim W$ (and, btw, its kernel determines the 'direction' of the projection).

Comment: Okay nice! That acutally made alot of sense to me. Thanks!